# String concatenation of two attributes in Rails where query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Let's say I have the attrs `first_name` and `last_name` for a User. I know the user's full name is "Johnny Appleseed", as I have a large Hash of user's full names as strings.

Sure, I could split each string first, and search like so:
`User.where(first_name: 'Johnny', last_name: "Appleseed")`

BUT, I'm wondering if there is a way to basically concat the two in a query, essentially like so:
`User.where('first_name + last_name = ?', 'Johnny Appleseed')`

Or if I could have a full_name method on the User model, and search by that?

```
 def full_name
    "#{self.first_name} #{self.last_name}"
  end
```

`User.where('full_name = ?', 'Johnny Appleseed')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the easiest solution would be:

```
User.where(%q(concat_ws(' ', first_name, last_name) = ?), 'Johnny Appleseed')
```

Comment: this works, thanks! Performance-wise, it's slow, but it gets the job done. I was unaware of `concat_ws`, thanks for showing me something new.